# Build system for multi-language project

Tags: maven, makefile

I am getting ready to embark on a project mainly for experimenting with languages, but also with a hint of usefulness. It will consist of a server-application, written in Erlang, and client-libraries in a number of languages. Initially I will want to write clients in Java, Ruby and Python. The actual protocol for communication will be Thrift.

I'm looking for a build system that will allow me to build the server and all the client libraries in one go, running unit-tests in each language, then packaging up a releasable artifact of some sort in whatever way is the "standard" for each language.

That means a Jar for Java, a RubyGem and a distribute/setuptools tarball for Python. Erlang probably has something too, but I'm not yet familiar with that.  It should also be able to run the Thrift compiler to generate the various Thrift-stubs in each language.

On the pad at the start is Maven. I'm fairly certain Maven can do all I need, but I fear it's too Java-centric, and leaves me with a ton of work for every new language I need to add.

Comment: Make is sort of a script language designed for build management; it delegates the work to compilers, linkers, etc. If you know how to do these things from the command line, it's pretty easy to do it with Make

Answer (score 0):

well one should know what the requirements are for every language to create a deliverable artifact.

if copy files from here to there and zip it is enough maven could cover most of the scripting languages. 
But you may end up writing plug-ins to support a custom packaging (which is not that complicated, so if there is no build system that may be a good choice).

It might not suit the build systems for every language to force maven upon them. So Maybe use the specific build tools available and wrap them in simple script and execute them using a continuous integration server (like bamboo, jenkings/hudson, teamcity, ...) to have them build in a specific order (to 'fake' dependencies)?

I'm not aware of a cross language system.

Gradle might be more flexible as its approach is more script oriented.

And there is http://eclipse.org/buckminster/ - just for completeness (havent had a look for quite some time)

regards

werner

Comment: I have looked around, and found that Maven has plugins for Erlang and Python, and possibly Ruby. For the first couple of languages I'm going to use, this solves the question of "how much work do I need to do to work around lacking support", and for that reason I'm awarding the bounty to this answer. I'm not really satisfied that Maven is the best possible, but it seems it's the best available for my exact usecase at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

```
"It will consist of a server-application, written in Erlang, 
and client-libraries in a number of languages. 
Initially I will want to write clients in Java, Ruby and Python. "
```

Maven is good if you follow its way. It is actually more of my way or high way. 
See: http://community.jboss.org/wiki/MavenVsGradle
For a lot of standard java projects it is actually very good. But if you need to use other things it becomes fairly complicated very quickly.

From your description it is on its way to become complicated very quickly.

I suggest to look gant (groovy + ant) and gradle. You can call other scripts from gant and/or gradle. JPython, JRuby will be your friend. Ant has a lot of tasks which will be very useful.

I have successfully implemented complicated Java/C++/C build project using Gant. Groovy scripting is powerful and easy to use. Gradle is similar and in some ways more powerful than gant.